# No code generators found with the name 'view'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app, and using VS 2022.

It's a simple web store project with a few products listed and shopping cart added.  The web site works, I can see products, details, pictures and add to shopping cart.

But when I try to add a Razor view of any object of any type (create, edit, list), I get this error:

> No code generators found with the name 'view'
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.GetCodeGenerator(String codeGeneratorName)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)

[image]

Project file has all references correct with correct versions:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>bbd1355e-1244-42ae-9d11-e1c7a7bd0a2b</UserSecretsId>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.16" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.16" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.16">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.16" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.16">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.1.30" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.16" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have latest packages installed, uninstalled and reinstalled and still get same error.

[image]

Checking available code generators shows that they are all installed:

[image]

I suspect it could be related to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` package, but I'm not sure how to get around it without it, since it's needed for the project.

I spent the last 2 days googling, but could not find a solution.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Elaborate on "add a razor view of any object of any type", what steps are taking?

Comment: For example right click on the  object folder in "view" folder, --> add view --> razor view --> choose view name, template (edit, create, list), model class and context class --> add.   visual studio tries to do scaffolding, generatig code but then throws this error..

Comment: what does `dotnet tool list -g` show?

Comment: you may try uninstall tool as suggested here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-7.0#uninstall-aspnet-codegenerator

Comment: It shows:  dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator 7.0.9   and dotnet-ef 7.0.10

Comment: I tried to reinstall, but it did not help.  After doing more digging and trying to create view from terminal i get this error ''' "  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=6.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" '''

Comment: "For example right click on the object folder in "view" folder, " Do you means `Views`  folder?

Comment: yes, but it can be any other folder too..

Answer (score 1):

> trying to create view from terminal i get this error ''' " Could not
> load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
> Version=6.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Try to add package  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design  6.0.21`

Change the Version to 6.0.21 like below:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.21">
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  Did not work.

Comment: Hi@mer063  ,  I think it was related to the packages version, not  related to DBcontext declaration, because I add declaration in program.cs, and connection string in appsettings.json too. I add the package  6.0.16 and reproduce the error, then I replace the latest packages, and it works. Maybe about reinstall problem, we need make sure we install the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design  6.0.21` .

Comment: This is possible.  Good to know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating new project, and building everything from 0.
Installed all latest packages. I think the problem was related to DBcontext declaration, its declaration in program.cs, and connection string in appsettings.json. But still not sure why, because when i tried to fix everything in existing project to match new project - it did not work..  maybe some internal bug.